# How can I start looping with item of index 1 from a php array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I would like to know, how to start looping of a php array with the second item.

Comment: What have you tried? Can be done with a `for` or a `foreach` on a sliced array

Comment: `$words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  
  for($count = 1; $count < count($words); $count++)
   echo $words[$count] . "<br />";` Something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the standard for loop to go through an array, for example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i] . " ";
}
```

Outputs "one two three four five".

Just set `$i` equal to 1 instead, like so:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i] . " ";
}
```

Now it outputs this: "two three four five".

However, if you wanted to get the last four items of an array, you can use `array_slice()`.

```
$sliced = array_slice($array, -4);

for($i = 0; $i < count($sliced); $i++) {
    echo $sliced[$i] . " ";
}
```

Outputs "two three four five".